# Perl script executed from ant exec task runs in wrong directory

Tags: perl, ant

OK, I have an issue that is driving me crazy.  I have set up an ant task that is designed to run a custom perl5-based build script that my company uses on a Solaris 10 system.  Below are the relevant portions of my build.xml file.

```
<target name="-init-user">
    <property file="${user.properties.file}"/>
    <!-- The two properties below are usually overridden -->
    <!-- by the active platform. Just a fallback. -->
    <property name="default.javac.source" value="1.4"/>
    <property name="default.javac.target" value="1.4"/>
</target>
<target name="-init-project" depends="-init-user">
    <property file="nbproject/project.properties"/>
</target>
<target name="-init-check" depends="-init-user,-init-project">
    <fail unless="src.dir">Must set src.dir</fail>
</target>
<target name="init" depends="-init-user,-init-project,-init-check"/>
<target name="bld_all" depends="init">
  <exec dir="${src.dir}" executable="perl5">
    <arg line="bld all"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Now if I put a print in this script to return the value of present working directory from the script's environment, it shows that it is running in ${ANT_HOME}/bin and not in ${src.dir} as it should be, which causes the script to fail to perform the build.  But just to make me insane, if I execute a pwd command directly as below, it returns the correct directory.

```
<target name="pwd_test" depends="init">
  <exec dir="${src.dir}" executable="pwd"/>
</target>
```

What is going on here?